# What kind of Privacy Policy is employed in UbuntuOne?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I want to ask:

1. Can someone else see or download my files from my UbuntuOne account?
2. Do I have complete privacy or not?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you do. Unless you decide to share those files with another person your files will be safe.

For more information on how to share files publicly please have a look at [is there a way to let someone without a UbuntuOne account download files](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/is-there-a-way-to-let-someone-without-a-ubuntu-one-account-download-files/).

And for more information on how a connection to the Ubuntu One servers is done visit the [Ubuntu wiki page over Ubuntu One security](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Security).

Comment: A rather important distinction is made in the wiki page you linked to: the files in Ubuntu One are **not** encrypted by the service and a customer's privacy is protected only by law, not by technical means. For example, an intruder or rogue Canonical employee would likely be able to retrieve the files.

Comment: Not any rogue canonical employee. Not even the team developing Ubuntu One has access to the servers where the user's files are stored.

Comment: @Rob, I doubt that. As stated here, files stored on the server are not encrypted: https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/are-my-files-stored-on-the-server-encrypted/